# How to handle multiple controlled tooltip of material UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on Material UI with react in my project. I am new to this.

I need tool-tip for each list with respected content. I am using MAP method to list items.

This is working fine on mouse-over . But I have controlled tooptip of onOpen and onClose.
if i set single state to open attribute onclick on particular list . it showing all tooltip at once.

I have individual tooltip controlled .

Please help me in this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an individual component for each map item, this way you can control the tooltip for all the childs, if you need more details add your code to help you